# getting error as soon as i am opening terminal.. -bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier

Tags: python, terminal

I'm getting this error when I open a terminal on my mac:

```
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: This very likely arises from an erroneous `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, or `.bashrc` file in your home directory, or from another file sourced by one of those.  We would need to have a look at those to say more.

Comment: You probably have a space before an `=` in your `.bashrc`. Something like `export PATH ='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:...`. Spaces are not allowed.

Comment: I do have spaces in Visual Studio Code ---- "...bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/.. " would this be causing the issue?